# subselect alternatives

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Take a look at this query, please:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `mterm1` > r.mterm1 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id) + 1 AS `pos_mt1_school`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `mterm1` > r.mterm1 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id AND class_id = r.class_id) + 1 AS `pos_mt1_class`,

    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `term1` > r.term1 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id) + 1 AS `pos_t1_school`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `term1` > r.term1 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id AND class_id = r.class_id) + 1 AS `pos_t1_class`,

    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `mterm2` > r.mterm2 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id) + 1 AS `pos_mt2_school`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `mterm2` > r.mterm2 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id AND class_id = r.class_id) + 1 AS `pos_mt2_class`,

    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `term2` > r.term2 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id) + 1 AS `pos_t2_school`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM result WHERE `term2` > r.term2 AND lesson_id = r.lesson_id AND class_id = r.class_id) + 1 AS `pos_t2_class`,

    r.*, student.* FROM result r

LEFT JOIN lessons lesson ON r.lesson_id = lesson.id
LEFT JOIN students student ON r.student_id = student.id
LEFT JOIN classes class ON student.class_id = class.id

WHERE student.id = 217 ORDER BY lesson.id ASC
```

I want to show student exam scores. So, first select his results (exam scores) from table `result`, then join `lessons` to show lesson name, and finally calculate student position in each lesson in his class and school. (based on his exam score)

That query works fine, but it takes about 2 seconds to be executed. (performance problem)

Is there any optimization for that query? (and an alternative for its subselect queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing cumulative counts in the subselects.

I cannot readily think of another way of doing this in MySQL in a single query.  If the ">" where an "=", this could be turned into a join.  But that is not possible in this case.

You can turn this into an explicit cross join with an aggregation, using a query such as this:

```
SELECT sum(case when r2.mterm1  > r.mterm1 then 1 else 0 end)+1 as `pos_mt1_school`,
       sum(case when r2.mterm1 > r.mterm1 and r2.class_id = r.class_id) + 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS `pos_mt1_class`,
       . . .
    r.*, student.*
FROM result r LEFT JOIN
     lessons lesson
     ON r.lesson_id = lesson.id LEFT JOIN
     students student
     ON r.student_id = student.id LEFT JOIN
     classes class
     ON student.class_id = class.id join
     result r2
     on r.lesson_id = r2.lesson_id
WHERE student.id = 217
group by r.result_id
ORDER BY lesson.id ASC
```

I'm not sure this will be faster than the original version.  The original version, by the way, would be sped up by putting on two indexes:  result(lesson_id, term2) and result(less_id, class_id, term2).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your query executed in 0.0517 seconds. a lot better than original query. (mysql said your query has some syntax errors. on line 2, you forgot `then 1 else 0 end`, and in last join, `on` is forgotten)